# Specs2 tests fails under terminal but work under Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea, sbt, specs2

I'm working on Play 2.5 application in Scala and I'm using Specs2 for testing. Here is my test class:

```
class Entity1ServiceSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
  private val entity1Repository = mock[Entity1Repository]
  private val entity1Service: Entity1Service = new Entity1ServiceImpl(entity1Repository)

  "Create AddedMessage" should {
    "return true" in {
      running(FakeAppBuilder.buildFakeApp) {
        entity1Repository.create(0, "911", "01", 20) returns true
        val result = entity1Service.create(0, "911", "01", 20)
        there was one(entity1Repository).create(0, "911", "01", 20)
        result shouldEqual true
      }
    }

    "return false" in {
      running(FakeAppBuilder.buildFakeApp) {
        entity1Repository.create(1, "911", "01", 10) returns false
        val result = entity1Service.create(1, "911", "01", 10)
        there was one(entity1Repository).create(1, "911", "01", 10)
        result shouldEqual false
      }
    }
  }
```

}

When I run the tests under Intellij Idea, everything works well but when I run it under the terminal using sbt test it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
[error] cannot create an instance for class services.Entity1ServiceSpec
[error]   caused by org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
[error] Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
[error] 
[error] -> at org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.any(MockitoMatchers.scala:45)
```

Can someone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:

```
@Singleton
class DefaultDBProvider @Inject() (val dbApi: DBApi) extends DBConnectionProvider {
  override def withConnection[A](block: (Connection) => A): A =
    dbApi.database("default").withConnection(block)
}    
class Entity1RepositoryImpl @Inject() (val db: DefaultDBProvider) {
  def create(some args) = {
    db.withConnection { implicit conn => SQL("some sql").execute()
    }
  }  
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I have another test class which works well. Nevertheless, when I replaced

```
val e2 = Entity2(any[Long], any[Long], "11111", any[String], any[String], any[ZonedDateTime])
```

on

```
val e2 = Entity2(0, 0, "11111", "111111", "text", ZonedDateTime.now())
```

Entity1ServiceSpec has started to work well too. How is it possible, that the error I had was like cannot create an instance for class services.Entity1ServiceSpec, but the actual problem was in Entity2ServiceSpec?

Comment: Is your `create` method taking an implicit argument maybe?

Comment: @Eric I've added Entity1RepositoryImpl. Please, take a look.

Comment: I don't understand your error at all actually. You spec fails to be instantiated which makes me think that your `private val` are creating the problem. On the other hand the error is related to the use of `any` which I don't see being called anywhere. Can you make a small project reproducing this issue?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error in a separate small project with the same repositories and service, but it works well while in my real project this problem occurs. By the way, the problem disappears, if I create Entity1RepositoryImpl manually without mocking.

Comment: Can you try to use `lazy val` for your variables and to use `org.mockito.Mockito.mock(classOf[Entity1RepositoryImpl])` instead of the function provided by specs2?

Comment: Please, see UPDATE 2. I have no idea how are that two tests connected, but now all tests pass.

Comment: No idea, maybe you have some injection magic going on?